# S3 access denied for cloudformation import existing resources using the cicd pipeline

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have created a cicd pipeline to import the existing resources in cloudformation. I want to Import the existing S3 bucket and encrypt it, all through the codepipeline only. I have used codebuild & codepipeline but I am getting an error while running the buildspec.yaml:

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet
> operation: S3 error: Access Denied

I can import and work on the same thing using console, and I have added access in both codepipeline & codebuild roles.

My buildspec.yml deploys following command:

```
- aws cloudformation create-change-set --stack-name ${STACK_NAME} --change-set-name ImportChangeSet --change-set-type IMPORT --resources-to-import file://ResourcesToImport.txt --template-url https://Bucket_Name.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/templates/Template_Import.yaml
```

Comment: What is yoru `buildspec.yaml`? What IAM roles do codebuild have?

Comment: @Marcin I have edited for the buildspec, and the IAM role contains s3, codebuild & cloudformation permissions for codebuild.

Comment: I mean exactly, the actual IAM roles and permissions that codebuild has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who couldn't solve the above error:
I tried with `--template-body` instead of `--template-url` and it worked, because there was a issue with the url I provided in my cli command. So the above command changed to this:

```
aws cloudformation create-change-set --stack-name ${STACK_NAME} --change-set-name ImportChangeSet --change-set-type IMPORT --resources-to-import "[{\"ResourceType\":\"AWS::S3::Bucket\",\"LogicalResourceId\":\"ImportedS3Bucket\",\"ResourceIdentifier\":{\"BucketName\":\"${Bucket_Name}\"}}]"
--template-body file://templates/template.yaml --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
```